# Using mouse from OSX host on iOS device

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, mouse, remote-control

Is it possible to use a mouse connected to OSX computer at iOS device.
Assume I have a Mac Mini and iPad on same WiFi network. I have a USB mouse connected to Mac Mini. Is there an option to use this USB mouse on iPad remotely (via WiFi) ?

I mean something like [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) - but Synergy work only on Windows, OSX and Linux. I want to one if there is something similar but for iOS and OSX or for Android and OSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the answer is no. iOS does not have a built in cursor function(unless you count the new keyboard cursor is iOS 9). In order to use a mouse on an iPad at all, you would probably need to jailbreak it.

Answer (score 1):

The design of iOS makes remote control not possible in the manner of KVM/remote pointer control.

There is no concept of pointer in iOS since the touch interface is multi-touch from the get go.

You could enable switch control or voiceover control and theoretically interface with that over the supported or non-supported (jailbreak) channel, but it's still not a true mouse pointer idiom.

- http://www.apple.com/ios/accessibility-tips/

There's tons of software on OS X for remote control of other devices, but you'd need to be more specific to let us help you. Nothing works from OS X to both Android or iOS due to design and architectural differences in those OS and interface design.