# Using a wireless mouse with an iPad

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, mouse, cursor

I need to use my iPad mini as a computer for a while. I am planning to use an Apple TV to AirPlay mirror my iPad's display to an existing HD monitor through HDMI, but I need a good input method. I am A LOT more productive and faster using a mouse, and I only really need a web browser.

I have found that Puffin Browser might have something similar to what I need, namely, it has a "virtual trackpad," where it puts a cursor on the screen and you can swipe around in a small rectangle to move and click the cursor on the page. This is all well and good, but I would need some way of using a physical, Bluetooth mouse somehow like this. Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: I am using a Bluetooth keyboard as well, which I already have gotten to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hurdles to overcome:

1. Apple's operating system does not pair with Bluetooth mice. You need to overcome that to use a mouse.
2. Apple's operating system is designed for multitouch as opposed to a single pointer, each application that you use will need to handle the mouse input and juggle it with other multitouch inputs.

You can review other people's failure to use a mouse with iOS on these questions:

- [Using mouse from OSX host on iOS device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203178/using-mouse-from-osx-host-on-ios-device)
- [How do I hover on the iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47016/how-do-i-hover-on-the-ipad/)

Basically keyboards and stylus are supported. Mice and trackpads are not currently.